# file version info is not working in foreign language OS

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

this is the code i am using to check for updates and then launch update file. Basically i check file version with online text and see which one is greater.

```
Dim wc As New WebClient()
        Dim upt As Double = Double.Parse(wc.DownloadString("someurl/update.txt"))

        Dim Info As FileVersionInfo
        Info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Application.StartupPath & "\app.exe")

        Dim curr As Double = Double.Parse(Info.FileVersion.Split(".")(0) & "." & Info.FileVersion.Split(".")(1) & Info.FileVersion.Split(".")(2))

        If (upt > curr) Then
            If (MessageBox.Show("Please Update app !!!", "Update Available", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then

                Dim ui As New updateinfo
                ui.RichTextBox1.Text = wc.DownloadString("someurl")
                ui.ShowDialog()

                Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & "\update.exe")
                Application.Exit()
            Else
                Application.Exit()
            End If
        End If
```

The problem is with non-english os which give me error like "input string was not in a correct format". How to fix it? Unfortunately i do not have access to any other language OS and want to get deep down into it.

Also any other method to check update would be good - i cannot use clickonce

Comment: There is very little point in using string parsing when you've got properties like FileMajorPart, etc, readily available.  Helps you avoid shooting your leg off with the number format in other cultures, not everybody uses a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Double.Parse("3.5", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (where `"3.5"` is your string). Some foreign-language OSs expect a comma as the decimal separator, which is what is making it crash. `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` basically means ["using English culture"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx), where the period will parse fine.

Comment: That being said, using a `double` to hold a version number has all kinds of problems in itself, for example inexact comparisons (depending how the rounding works – 3.5 would be fine, but 3.4 wouldn't).